# Error while running a container using docker

Tags: bash, ubuntu, docker, bin, linux-containers

I have installed docker in my machine
I could successfully pull images from the repository and the pulled images are clearly listed when I see the list of images pulled.
The docker service was also started using

```
sudo service docker start
```

However, when I try to run the same using the command,

```
sudo docker run -it ubuntu:12.04
```

I am getting the following error

> docker: Error response from daemon: Container command '/bin/bash' not
>   found or does not exist..

The issue remains the same for any image that I have tried with
What could be the reason for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your version of docker, but check if you have [issue 23411](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/23411), where adding a `workdir` is needed:

```
sudo docker run --workdir /var -it ubuntu:12.04
```

There seem to be some recent bug in [`start.go`](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/23411#issuecomment-224941229), and a [PR in progress](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22845).

Comment: I checked if the issue [issue 23411](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/23411) exists in my case. But I am getting the same error. Is there any way I can download a previous version of docker ?

Comment: @Ela what is your docker host and version? Are you on Windows using boot2docker?

Comment: I am using docker on ubuntu. And the version is 1.11.2

Comment: @Ela you could downgrade with https://forums.docker.com/t/how-can-i-install-a-specific-version-of-the-docker-engine/1993/8